# Porque é que o Português evoluiu para usar "Chá", ao contrário de todos os outros países da Europa?

Tags: etimologia

Todos os países da Europa ocidental, central e nórdica utilizam uma palavra para *chá* semelhante a *te/tea/té* (ou outra com a mesma raiz), enquanto que Portugal usa *Chá*.

[image]

Segundo a [Wikipédia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ch%C3%A1):

> Os primeiros europeus a contactar com o chá foram os portugueses que chegaram ao Japão em 1543.

Qual é a etimologia desta palavra? E da dos outros países? Porque é que o Português evoluiu de maneira diferente dos outros países?

Comment: Foneticamente tiá pode ter virado chá, ou não?

Comment: @AndréLyra Não creio... Parece ter sido por causa das duas pronúncias do caractér 茶.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A mesma página da [Wikipédia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ch%C3%A1) diz:

> O caracter chinês para chá é 茶, mas tem duas formas completamente distintas de se pronunciar. Uma é *te* que vem da palavra malaia para a bebida, usada pelo Dialeto Min que se encontra em Amoy. Outra é usada em cantonês e mandarim, que soa como *cha* e significa "apanhar, colher".

Portanto a etimologia desta palavra provêm da pronúncia cantonesa e mandarina, e a etimologia das outras palavras vem da pronúncia malaia.

Segundo o [artigo que contém o mapa](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-2507961/Mapping-migration-words-Infographic-reveals-roots-Europes-languages-countries-linked-wider-world.html) (na legenda deste):

> Languages spoken in eastern Europe and Asia which got their tea overland rather than from the Dutch tend to use forms such as *chai*.

Ou seja, que os países que importavam o seu chá dos Países Baixos utilizam a forma *té*, enquanto que os que importavam o seu chá do exterior da Europa usam a forma *chá*.